# How to break out of a program in an infinite loop?

Tags: linux, gcc, infinite-loop

When running a program that goes into an infinite loop in the terminal, how would I bring back the command prompt?

(I'm using Fedora core 5)

Comment: Fedora 5? As in "five"???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could send a SIGHUP (Ctrl-Z) or SIGTERM (Ctrl-C). The former merely pauses the program, you may resume with `fg` (or resume as a background process, using `bg`).

Comment: If Ctrl-C doesn't work, you can try the lesser-known Ctrl-\ which sends SIGQUIT.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to kill the program using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> where C stands for Cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Either Ctrl-C as mentioned, or if that should not work, open another terminal, find the process using ps -ef|grep , find the process ID (pid), and use the kill command: kill -9

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the program with `&` at the end to cause it run in the background. Note that if you exit the terminal, the application might/will stop as well.

```
root@root:~$ run_app with params &
```

Using `Ctrl+C` will kill it if you forgot the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

There is [no way to prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%3D_NP_problem) that any arbitrary program will ever end without actually running it to the end.

Having said that, it is possible to set up a watchdog via e.g. D-Bus that can kill a program if a response is not received within a given amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can simply add a & to the command line. You can also hit CTRL-Z (this puts the process in the Stopped state), and then type bg  to get it running in the background again...

Answer (score 0):

you can press ctrl + z
type: ps ux  ,to see the running process, if the one you want to kill is there

type: kill -9 processId , where the process id is the loop process id